# Data.Map vs Data.Map.Strict and Data.Map.Lazy

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I understand Data.Map.Lazy and Data.Map.Strict are different. But what exactly are you importing when you import Data.Map: the strict one, the lazy one or a combination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lazy one. Looking at the [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html) the

```
 module Data.Map.Lazy
```

means it's re-exporting all of the lazy stuff. It used to provide a few additional functions, but these are all deprecated in favor of `Data.Foldable` and the strict version of `Map`.

Edit: The second line of the documentation on the linked page states that it reexports the lazy version as well.

> An efficient implementation of ordered maps from keys to values (dictionaries).
>
> This module re-exports the value lazy Lazy API, plus several value strict functions from Strict.

The functions it mentions are all deprecated however.

Comment: Thanks. So what exactly is the reason that Data.Map exists then? Is it for compatibility reasons? Or does it act as a shortcut for importing Data.Map.Lazy?

Comment: @ZUAMLONY Bit of both, probably more compatibility. Most people's code (mine included) use `Data.Map`. It's fairly common though for Haskell's datastructures to be default lazy too.

Comment: I read the docs as well, but didn't quite get it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It exists for compatibility.